# Numerical Approximation of Lebesgue Integral (Real-Valued)

Tags: probability-theory, numerical-methods, lebesgue-integral

In the context of probability theory, I have come across $\int_{[a,b]} f(x)\ dQ(x)$ for some function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ and some measure $Q(x) = \exp(-\lambda \cdot x)$. Since $\frac{dQ(x)}{dx} = -\lambda \cdot \exp(-\lambda \cdot x)$ we can write 
 $$\int_{[a,b]} f(x)\ dQ(x) = -\int_{[a,b]} f(x)\cdot\lambda\cdot \exp(-\lambda \cdot x)\ dx$$

---

Questions:

1. *Theoretical Side*: I am not quite sure how $Q(x)$ defines a "measure", e.g. what is the measure of $[a,b]$? Is it $Q(b) - Q(a)$? What's the correct way of labeling $Q(x)$ and $dQ(x)$?
2. *Practical Side*: What if $Q(x)$ is a function (different to the one above), to which I don't know the derivative $\frac{dQ(x)}{dx}$. How can I numerically approximate the integral? Would this work:
   $$\int_{[a,b]} f(x)\ dQ(x) \quad\approx\quad \sum_{i=0}^{N-1} \frac{f(x_{i+1}) + f(x_{i})}{2} \cdot \Big(Q(x_{i+1}) - Q(x_{i})\Big)$$
   for some partition $a=x_0<\ldots < x_N=b$ ?
3. Are there better methods to numerically integrate than the method from (2)?

Comment: You will never be able to approximate general Lebesgue integrals, you need some regularity to be able to represent the functions as computer programs. So the integrals will be also Riemann or Riemann-Stieltjes. With that said, 1) yes, 2) yes 3) write the integral as $\int_{[Q(a),Q(b)]} f(Q^{-1}(s))ds$ and apply any quadrature method. This works best if $Q$ is monotonous and smooth enough for the order of the method.

Comment: But if I don't know $Q^{-1}(s)$, then all I can resort to is the method from (2)? Unless I numerically solve for $Q^{-1}(s)$, but that does not seem very efficient?